# Unable to understand some XSLT grouping code through <xsl:key and generate-id()

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have data in the below XML format

```
<item>
    <title>Body Cleaner</title>
    <vendor>Wipro</vendor>
    <location>EMEA</location>
    <manufacture_date>12/08/2010</manufacture_date>
    <item_type>House Hold</item_type>      
    <item_type>Health</item_type>                    
</item>
<item>
    <title>Sweet Catch up</title>
    <vendor>Unilever</vendor>
    <location>APAC</location>
    <manufacture_date>21/07/2013</manufacture_date>
    <item_type>House Hold</item_type>      
    <item_type>Kitchen</item_type>                    
</item>
```

(1) Below is code in a xsl file

```
<xsl:key name="groups" match="item_type" use="."/>
```

and

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item/item_type[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', .)[1])]"/>
```

here i am unable to understand the use  of generate-id() in that particular case . What is the purpose of below code

[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', .)[1])]

(1) Below is code in another xsl file

```
<xsl:key name="vendors" match="item" use="vendor"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item[count(.|key('vendors',vendor)[1])=1]">
```

here i am unable to understand the expression

> item[count(.|key('vendors',vendor)[1])=1]

specially the purpose of .| in count.

Could somebody help me to  make the ground here so that i can further understand the XSLT code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is called [muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). In xslt 1.0, there was no built in grouping.

Keys, like this one are used by the key() function:

```
<xsl:key name="vendors" match="item" use="vendor"/>
```

The key() function returns a node-set from the document, using the index specified by an  element ([info](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_key.asp)).

```
item[count(.|key('vendors',vendor)[1])=1]
```

This will see whether a node set is made up of the two nodes has one or two nodes in it (e.g.grouping). This basically identifies the groups. Once you have Identified the groups you can visit each node in the key.